# Printing multiple files using process.start

Tags: c#

Here I have code that opens Adobe and causes it to print a PDF file using `Process.Start()`. I am trying to print multiple files (two different pdfs) using the same command. How would I go about this? This is what I have so far:

```
 Process profilePrintProcess = new Process();
                profilePrintProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                profilePrintProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    Verb = "PrintTo",
                    FileName = "[" + profFileName + " " + contractFileName + "]",
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                };

                profilePrintProcess.Start();
```

I've been using this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/print.mspx?mfr=true) as a guide per another SO question that referenced a similar issue.

Comment: Looking at the Developer FAQ for adobe reader http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/intro_to_sdk/DeveloperFAQ.pdf it looks like there is only a way to print one file at a time.  You'll have to move your code to a method and call the method for each file you would like to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to print a single file trough Acrobat Reader try this and let me know if worked:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "AcroRd32.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/p " + YourPDFFilePath;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

to printig multipile pdf files first combine them and next print combined document trough [PDFSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=24&Itemid=35)

```
var outputPDFDocument = PdfDocument.Combine("Output.pdf", "doc1.pdf", "doc2.pdf", "doc3.pdf");
outputPDFDocument.Save("C:\\temp.pdf"); 

PdfFilePrinter.AdobeReaderPath = @"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 8.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";  
PdfFilePrinter.DefaultPrinterName = "Take printer";   
PdfFilePrinter printer = new PdfFilePrinter(@"C:\\temp.pdf");  
printer.Print();
```

Comment: to print two different pdfs would I do `startInfo.Arguments = "/p" + file1 + " " + file2`?